# Button/Element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium, button, xpath

I am trying to click on a button in a webpage using `Selenium` and `xpath`. I managed to click on a button in the previous page but after loading into this new page, I tried to use the same code but different button HTML, it was not able to load as before.

My code is as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get("https://connect.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='p-button p-component']").click() #button workable


In the next page:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='add icon-only proto-button ng-star-inserted']").click() #button not working
```

The error message that I have received is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

I have also tried with adding in waiting time as below, but it is still not working.

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='add icon-only proto-button ng-star-inserted']")))
button.click()
```

However, now the error message that I have received is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Alternatively, I have tried to work on other elements of the HTML code, for example. But either way, the button did not work.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='proto-icon ng-star-inserted']").click()

or

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//connect-button[@class='proto-button-list-item ng-star-inserted']").click()
```

[The HTML is in the picture attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhYtT.png)

I have no idea how else can i try to work around. Please advise, thanks !

Comment: I guess the `/button` is covered by `/connect-button`, so it's not clickable. Did you try to click it with JSclick?

Comment: Hi @lucasnguyen17, I am really new into Python and Selenium, I'm not really sure how to do that. Can you roughly show me how does it look like ?  And yes, from the HTML, can see that the /connect-button is above the /button element.

Comment: okay I think I would need creds to login right here https://www.brandforce.com/domain/connect.com/ ? if so, I do not have them. Please share the HTML for button which you wanna click ?

Comment: @ejbeh `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='p-button p-component']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)`

Comment: thanks @lucasnguyen17 i have tried with ```element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='add icon-only proto-button ng-star-inserted']")``` and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @lucasnguyen17

The button `element` must be not clickable because of the `connect-button` element over it.

So

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='p-button p-component']") 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

It's really simple,

In the first line it stores the element as a python variable.
Then it runs the js script.

```
element.click();
```

Where the element is your specific button. You can try it on the console to test if it works.

A link to the specific page would have been helpful.